# How to get the max value for elements having the same id under Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Using `Laravel/Eloquent`, I would like to retrieve the max value for each `week_id` in the following table.

```
 +---------+-----------+
 | week_id |     value |
 +---------+-----------+
 |    5    |           |
 |    6    |         1 |
 |    6    |           |
 |    6    |           |
 |    7    |         3 |
 |    7    |         4 |
 |    7    |           |
 +---------+-----------+
```

With `MySql` I would do it like this:

```
SELECT week_id, max(value) as max_value FROM foo_table GROUP BY week_id
```

=>

```
+---------+-----------+
| week_id | max_value |
+---------+-----------+
|       5 |           |
|       6 |         1 |
|       7 |         4 |
+---------+-----------+
```

How could I achieve the same under Laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 DB::table('foo_table')
    ->select('week_id', DB:raw('max(value) as max_value'))
    ->groupBy('week_id')
    ->get();
```